Docker and MariaDB, really very slow query
I rarely come here to ask questions, since I usually find answers by digging hard, but this time I didn't see solutions and I'm really very frustrated.
I am setting up a docker container with MariaDB, with this Dockerfile:
FROM mariadb:latest
WORKDIR /app

I compile this Dockerfile with:
docker build --rm -t mysql_mariadb .
And I have this docker-compose.yml:
name: mariadb_app
services:
  app:
    image: mysql_mariadb
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "test"
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    networks:
      - nets
    volumes:
      - ./Config/mariadb.cnf:/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf:ro
      - C:/Docker/Data/MariaDB_DATA:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
  nets:
    external: true

And I use this to start container:
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build -d
And finally this is "mariadb.cnf" file:
[mysqld]
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
max_allowed_packet = 256M
port = 3307

I access it from PHPMyAdmin, and everything seems fine. It connects well and the database works. Everything was going well until I migrated a significant amount of data, and ran a query that involved several tables.. here began a problem for which I still have not found any solution.
The query:
SELECT a.id, a.name AS name, a.label AS label, c.name AS category, a.plays,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_favorites WHERE audio_id = a.id) AS favs
FROM audios AS a
INNER JOIN audio_categories AS c ON a.category_id = c.id
ORDER BY c.datetime ASC, a.datetime ASC;

(Please don't comment about possible improvements to the query, that's not why I'm here)
I have same MariaDB database with wamp64 (Windows server), and it have exactly same tables and data, and I ran exactly same query. In PHPMyAdmin, the result was this:
Showing rows 0 - 24 (total of 1745, The query took 0.6545 seconds.)
When I run the query in the container database, this is what I get:
Showing rows 0 - 24 (total of 1745, The query took 31.6956 seconds.)
0.6 secs vs 31.69 secs. How is this possible?
I tried everything, I changed all settings in the mariadb.cnf file, I checked resource usage (I already allocated more cpus and ram in the yml), this also happens by executing the query locally in the container so it is not a network problem.
I even tried not using mariadb:latest image, using a debian and installing mariadb manually. Same results... I don't know what else to do and I don't know why there is such a difference in time if it is the same database, with the same configuration, the same data and the same query.
I read an answer that suggested modifying the "innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit" setting to 2 or 0. Also no results..
Everything indicates that it is a docker and resource allocation problem, but nothing I have tried worked for me.
I've been very stuck with this for days, and I really need help.
Thanks.

Its entirely possible that the "fast" database has indexes that the "slow" database does not have.

@topsail Thanks for your reply. I designed the structure of all tables, and I did not add any type of index, they only have primary keys

The host is Windows and the image is Linux. I wouldn't be surprised if that's the reason. It could be the virtualization or the different filesystems. Can you try it with a Linux host and or Windows image?

https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-extremely-slow-on-linux-and-windows/129752/2 According to this link, it's either WSL, Docker Desktop or a different filesystem. AFAIK the Docker engine without Docker Desktop on Linux has overhead < 5%.

@jabaa Thanks for your reply. Right now I created a Cloud server with Debian to check what you tell me, and install MariaDB, phpMyAdmin, import all data and run the same query.. it tooks 0.8 secs. It seems that the problem is not Linux :(

@jabaa Reading more carefully your answer, I understood what you meant. The problem is the Windows WSL.. I tried installing docker in Debian, and in that container the query took 0.9 seconds. Thank you so much! Please add answer in detail to the post

ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON could validate if out of data statistics on the WSL was the problem or just a poorer query plan was chosen. Even emulating Linux interfaces the slowdown is more than what I'd expect. Also WAMP appears to 11.2.2 while the mariadb:latest is 11.3.2. Does analyze table tablename persistent for all) improve the query performance to a near comparible response time?

Are you running into Docker on WSL2 very slow?  You can't directly use the MySQL database files; does changing from a bind mount to a named volume improve the performance?

please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of select version(); and show create table ... for all three tables (for both docker and wamp64, if there are any differences at all) and explain SELECT...rest of your query

are you running this query in your code as well?  iiuc phpmyadmin is adding a LIMIT clause to your query, and you are showing a difference in performance with that LIMIT, but does it also differ without it?

Thanks for the comments, but the question is solved, the problem was the WSL, I replaced it with Hyper V and the performance improved significantly

Solved. The problem was the WSL in Windows, I replaced it with Hyper V (at Docker Desktop install setup) and the performance improved significantly. When I can, I will install everything on Linux to stop having problems. Thank you all for your comments.


How is this possible


The Optimizers in MySQL and MariaDB have diverged significantly.
The faster one probably reformulates the query -- Please provide EXPLAIN SELECT ... ; SHOW WARNINGS; for each server.
The query provided seems to be incomplete -- Where does "showing rows 0-24" come from?  It's as if the UI is tacking on LIMIT 25.  _This may be changeing the query optimization significantly.  So, manually tack on LIMIT 25 for those explains.
If it is resource allocation, let's see innodb_buffer_pool_size.  Also, check whether the slow one was using a lot more I/O.

If the SHOW WARNINGS does not present a more efficient formulation, I will provide such.  (even though you don't want such)
(innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit should be irrelevant since you are not INSERTing.)

I specifically said that I did not want improvement comments about the query, the problem does not come from there. It was already resolved, it was the Windows WSL. HyperV solved the problem. Thanks anyway.

@Crisher - As a kindness to others, self-Answer the question explaining what the issue with WSL was.

@RickJames  What political office are you running for?  Be kind to others.  :) You know you are Loved!! by the community.

@WilsonHauck - Hehe (and thanks).  But apparently not by two downvoters.
